# very simple code, and getting error C2712, could not understand why

Tags: c++, visual-studio, try-except

I'm having trouble for a while with `error C2712: Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding`, after narrowing the problem, I was left with a very very simple code, and i can not understand why it causes this error. I am using Visual Studio under windows.

I am compiling with /EHa (I do not use /EHsc)

The reason I use `__try/__except` and not `try/catch` is because I want to catch ALL the errors, and do not want the program to crash under any circumstances, including for example division by 0, that try-catch does not catch.

```
#include <string>
static struct myStruct
{
    static std::string foo() {return "abc";}
};

int main ()
{
    myStruct::foo();

    __try 
    { }
    __except (true)
    { }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
error C2712: Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding
```

Comment: You are probably misguided in this desire to catch **all** exceptions. Anyway, to make this work, I think you need to move the `__try`/`__catch` blocks to a different function.

Comment: @Praetorian i did that, and it works, but all my main is full with static functions, and i want the try-except to be over all the main

Comment: What if you move everything within `main()` into another function (`do_main`), and then do `__try { do_main(); } ...`?

Comment: It might work, but what is the problem in this example? Why is it not working?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message exactly? Do you not understand why your function requires object unwinding? Do you not know that `__try` can't be used in a function that does? Are you looking for a workaround? (If so, we'll need to know more details about your specific use case.)

Comment: Were I to stab a guess (and i'd probably be way off base but that rarely stops me) you can thank MS's extended lifetime of references to temporaries for this.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The string object returned by `myStruct::foo()` requires stack unwinding for destruction, and catching SEH exceptions is not supported in such functions.

Comment: @Praetorian Isn't the destructor of `std::string` *supposed* to be long-gone before entering `__try`, or are the restrictions on setting up SEH function wide and not just no throw within the SEH construct? I rarely use them, and never in code like this, so I honestly don't know.

Comment: @Praetorian I checked again, it will not work, I have to use a static struct before the `__try` and then during the `__except` to handle its data

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah the string is destroyed at the end of that function call, but I think just having it in the same scope is not allowed. I don't know much about SEH, I've only used it once to debug a crash, and I moved everything within `main` to another function, and then wrapped that function call in a __try/__catch.

Comment: @user1438233 I don't understand why you have *anything* outside of the `__try`. Move *everything* within `main` into another function and call that function from within the `__try` block.

Comment: @Praetorian Say I have a data structure that I fill with data, if in the middle of the filling a have an error, I want in the `catch` to send the data I already have, so I must set the data structure out of the `__try`

Comment: add a language-tag for the version of compiler that you are using, this question is specific to that

Comment: @MattMcNabb This happens in VS2010 and VS2013, so i added VS tag

Comment: @WhozCraig The error message pretty clearly explains the (somewhat extreme) limitation, "Cannot use __try in **functions** that require object unwinding".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution. For more details read [Compiler Error C2712](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwtb73ad(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
#include <string>
struct myStruct
{
    static std::string foo() {return "abc";}
};

void koo()
{
    __try 
    { }
    __except (true)
    { }
}

int main ()
{
    myStruct::foo();   
    koo();
    return 0;
}
```

**Extra Note**: no need `static` if no declaration using your struct (myStruct).

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense as you don't protect *your* code with `__try`/`__except`.