# GDIPlus in a multithreaded environment inside a DLL and in the main app

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

I have an application that catalogs image files on my computer.  In CWinApp::InitInstance, I initialize Gdiplus using the following:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

also, in the init function of my library class, I do the same.

Finally, because I spawn a separate thread to perform this task, I initialize GDI+ again at the beginning of the thread proc.  The meat and potatoes of this is a call to the following code:

```
void CImageEntry::UpdateInformation()
{
    if (IsRemoteFile())
    {
        UpdateRemoteFileInformation();
        return;
    }

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(m_csPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile && hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FILETIME CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime;
        GetFileTime(hFile, &CreationTime, &LastAccessTime, &LastWriteTime);
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&CreationTime, &m_sysCreationTime);
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&LastAccessTime, &m_sysLastAccessTime);
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&LastWriteTime, &m_sysLastWriteTime);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        Sleep(10);
        hFile = NULL;
    }
    try
    {
        Gdiplus::Image img(m_csPath.c_str());
        if (img.GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Status::Ok)
        {
            UINT totalBufferSize = 0;
            UINT numProperties = 0;
            img.GetPropertySize(&totalBufferSize, &numProperties);
            Gdiplus::PropertyItem* pAllItems = (Gdiplus::PropertyItem*)malloc(totalBufferSize);
            img.GetAllPropertyItems(totalBufferSize, numProperties, pAllItems);
            free(pAllItems);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        
    }
}
```

using Image::FromFile for a pointer is failing as well.  The exception crashes my application despite the try/catch block.  m_csPath has been previously validated and thus guaranteed to exist here.

Comment: At the beginning of the thread the code:
 GdiplusStartupInput gdipsi;
 GdiplusStartupOutput gdipso;
 Status stat = GdiplusStartup(&token, &gdipsi, &gdipso);

returns stat == Status::Ok and token = 418150485

Then it crashes with the following:

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9D41E6C34 (gdi32full.dll) in PhotoTeca.exe: 0xC0000006: In page error reading location 0x000002CE29EA0028 (status code 0xC0000185).

Comment: Use SEH instead if you plan to catch the exception (or if you want to catch the exceptions globally you can install a Vectored Exception handler). Because the exception is not a C++ one.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but the code is being called from the DLL.  The DLL spawned the thread

Comment: The error is `STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR` - generally look here for those [NT statuses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55).

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2712 Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding ImageLibrary c:\users\tarie\source\repos\photolibrary\imagelibrary\imageentry.cpp 72

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701426/cannot-use-try-in-functions-that-require-object-unwinding-fix

Comment: Use direct 2d gdi+ is really old.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, is Direct 2d readily available without an extra download?

Comment: NOTE:  I don't need to display anything in the DLL.  I just need to read the metadata from the image to help catalog it

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions, it's weird I was able to open the file directly and get the date information and even get file attributes to check if the file should be stored, but GDI + crashes

Comment: Yes, its included in Windows since Vista.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you may want to try the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) instead. It is likely to get you better performance over GDI+ when reading metadata only (GDI+ uses the WIC internally, too). Direct2D doesn't buy you anything here; it is a rendering API only.